# How to return any inherited class that inherits it via a function from the root class?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that inherits a particular class where I've put all my initialization code. I currently cast it as T in order to return my new class.

```
abstract class RootRepository<out T> : KodeinInjected {

    override val injector: KodeinInjector = KodeinInjector()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun init(kodein: Kodein): T {
        injector.inject(kodein)
        return this as T
    }

}
```

Let's say I have a function and a class called NewRepo.

```
class NewRepo: RootRepository<NewRepo>() {

    private val mangaDao by injector.instance<MangaDao>()
    private val api by injector.instance<Api>()


    fun getMangaList() {
        //Some code here
    }

    fun fetchMangaList(){
        //Some code here
    }

}
```

In a different class I have this.

```
val newRepo:NewRepo = NewRepo.init(appKodein())
```

Is there a better way to do this than casting?

Comment: Use 'Any'. It works like object in Java.

Comment: You class doesn't extend `T`. It just depends in some way on `T`. In my opinion the compiler shows a correct warning. Does this really work?

Comment: @dipdipdip Yes it actually works, I don't mind the warning, I'm just wondering if there are any alternative methods towards this.